# Problem with ngmodel and radio with a integer value

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-ngmodel

I want to get my value and put it in my checkbox, if I change the type from radio to number i can see my value  :

in a for :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="project.duration" type="number" value="{{d.title}}" ...
```

result : number input with my value inside.

But i want to be able to get my value with radio button

```
<input [(ngModel)]="project.duration" type="radio" value="{{d.title}}"...
```

d is my duration : 
public durations: any = [
    {
      title: 1,
      id: '1'
    },
    {
      title: 2,
      id: '2'
    }...

result just empty radios buttons

any ideas ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696413/1009922) and [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcw9f6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Perfect Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

To set the radio button value as a number, I need to use the bracket notation: [value]="0"

source : [How to check a Radio Button based on the ngModel it is associated with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696304/how-to-check-a-radio-button-based-on-the-ngmodel-it-is-associated-with/54696413#54696413)

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot!

Comment: By the way, you can select your answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `value` attribute to get the value. Like this-

```
<input [(ngModel)]="project.duration" value="1" type="radio">
```

Live Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-button-value

Comment: already have it , post updated i also tried to put my own value like you does